# How to connect and find a user from Azure AD using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, ldapjs

I am trying to find a user from the azure active directory using nodejs. I am using [Node-ActiveDirectory](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory#findUser) for this task. First I tried to connect to the Azure active directory as the given example in the [above link](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory#findUser). example code as below that I have used.

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var config = { url: 'ldap://myhotmail.onmicrosoft.com',
    baseDN: 'dc=myhotmail,dc=onmicrosoft,dc=com',
    username: 'roledene@myhotmail.onmicrosoft.com',
    password: 'myPassword'
}
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);

var username = 'roledene@myhotmail.onmicrosoft.com';
var password = 'myPassword';

ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }

    if (auth) {
        console.log('Authenticated!');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Authentication failed!');
    }
});
```

but it gives the following error. what is wrong with this code ?

```
ERROR: {"code":"ENOTFOUND","errno":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"myhotmail.onmicrosoft.com","host":"myhotmail.onmicrosoft.com","port":389}
```

Comment: The error means that is not an actual routable domain. I don't think Azure AD supports LDAP without AAD DS. Typically you query Azure AD by using Microsoft Graph API. Even though it has AD in the name, it is quite a different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @juunas comment, I tried with the Microsoft Graph client.

I will quote the initial step for setup the ms graph client which is exactly mentioned in [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript) for more details

### Installing ms graph client

```
npm install @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client
```

### connect and query from MS graph api

```
const MicrosoftGraph = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");

var client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
    authProvider: (iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) => {
        done(null, {
            profile,
            accessToken,
            refreshToken
        }); //first parameter takes an error if you can't get an access token
    }
});

// Example calling /me with no parameters
client
    .api('/me')
    .get((err, res) => {
        console.log(res); // prints info about authenticated user
    });
```